# Information on Mma v10

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My workplace had two Wolfram reps come yesterday and give a brief intro for inexperienced Mma users, and previews of v10 for more experienced users.  This isn't so much a question, but I think the community would be interested to know, for example,

1. that we should expect v10 in the next 60 to 90 days.
2. that there will be a new list-like object called an Association, which is more like a table of key/value pairs

   ```
   assoc = <| key1-> val1, key2->val2, ... |>
   ```

   which you can access (iirc) in a manner like

   ```
   Part[assoc, Key[key1]]
   (* val1 *)
   ```

   and similar double-bracket syntactic sugar which is sort of a bare-bones data- or object- structure.  This is related to some improvements to the curated data available in Mma.
3. that v10 will introduce a new kind of evaluation control, which is something like

   ```
   Inactive[f][arg1, arg2, ...]
   ```

   where the args will be evaluated but the head f will not.  You can then Activate to release the hold.
4. that there will be a number of changes to the default graphics, including color scheme.  Also, there will be a number of built-in plot Themes, which are essentially shorthands for groups of options that look nice together, eg.:

   ```
   Plot[ ... , PlotTheme->"Detailed"]
   ```

   which is a simple way to add dotted grid lines, a legend (or color bar, depending on the kind of plot), etc.  Other Themes I saw include "Business" which had bolder lines and brighter colors, "Default" (or was it "Classic"?) that gives you the old Mma plot style.  You will be able to make your own themes which will save to somewhere in the user's library in a .m file, which you can then share with others.  There will also be some built-in journal-specific themes (the example the reps kept giving was Nature, mentioning one- and two-column formats).  Additionally, there will be improved custom tick control.
5. that v10 will support retina displays.
6. that there will allegedly be for-real multi-step undo!

and that, of course, the reps acknowledged that v10 is still in development and all is subject to change.

So, maybe to ask something concrete: is there a place where people are discussing v10?  Is this post appropriate for the meta.mma stack exchange?

Comment: The online documentation for M10 has been up for a while, because of RPi, and most of these are known. I've used `Association` in [an answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38391/5), few others have used v10 functions, `PlotTheme` was present in v9, [albeit hidden inside ``Charting` ``](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=10935632#10935632), [retina in v10 is known](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30104/5), Undo was also mentioned by someone (perhaps after the conference)... Nevertheless, I'm glad to know it's only about 3mo away! :) Hope you didn't violate any NDAs.

Comment: @rm-rf `Charting` has quite a lot of stuff inside of it. Useful backtesting algorithms for finance ...which are hidden.

Comment: Nope, no NDAs :)  I will have to take a look at Charting`.

Comment: Oh!  I forgot one:  WhenEvent may work in DSolve (not just NDSolve), yielding piecewise functions.

Comment: The v10 on the RPi has no real undo, so I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: @bobthechemist if you have OS X and run Mma as a service from within e.g. TextEdit you get multiple undos!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Can you elaborate on that?  I think you may have mentioned it before, but that was before I started using OS X ... Do you have a link?

Comment: @mike would be very interested in that as well.

Comment: oooooh, that Association thing looks sexy.

Comment: Here's [PlotTheme](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).

Comment: Multi-step undo! It's about time.

Comment: Here's [Association](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html?q=Association)

Comment: For me point 3 looks very promissing :) Can't wait to test it's potential.

Comment: @Szabolcs , Sjoerd see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/how-do-you-get-high-resolution-plots-in-applications-using-the-mathematica-maths  Unfortunately I have been asking WRI to update this since 2009. I have also asked them to make the code available if they do not intend to update it but they have declined. This is still useable on older Macs (for e.g. multiple undo) but the graphics produced is low res crap.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries maybe raising this on the Wolfram community might spark a response from WRI. (Szabolcs)

Comment: @Mike I was actually referring to your earlier comment about back testing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It is all undocumented but has been there since V8. This information is courtesy of WRI. Unfortunately I do not now how to format back ticks in comments. `Options[Charting`BackTesting]`. An example: `Manipulate[
 Charting`BackTesting[
  FinancialData["GOOG", "OHLCV", {{2010, 1}, Date[]}], "LRS", 
  "AveragePeriod" -> p, Method -> "Report", "TransactionCost" -> 3.5, 
  "InitialInvestment" -> 10000], {{p, 21, "Periods"}, 5, 30, 1}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, "Linear Regression Slope Backtesting"}]`

Comment: [Mathematica 10 is Coming Soon](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica-10-coming-soon.html).

Comment: I used Mathematica 10 on Raspberry Pi to compile a list of functions in v10 that aren't in v9 http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5220

Comment: Wow, it took them 10 major versions to implement undo. That's amazing progress!

Comment: It's roughly 60 days from the original post, and preliminary Wolfram Language documentation is still missing considerable amount of pieces. I wonder if they actually use the same definition of day as the rest...

Comment: @WalkingRandomly, that list is not complete as a lot of functions are missing e.g. non of the `*Mesh*` functions are listed (`DelaunayMesh`, `ConvexHullMesh`, `VoronoiMesh` etc.). The `Area` and `Volume` functions are also missing just to name a few.

Comment: Then I guess they were missing from the raspberry Pi version at the time I ran it?

Comment: The following video was recorded in the beginning of June, describes various new features in Mathematica 10, and maybe most interestingly has a statement right on the end of it saying release would occur within weeks instead of months. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr0QQZJj_nk

Comment: @kirma Since it is now June 30, I wonder whether this "weeks" statement is still applicable.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I remember reading of similar (even less official) claims already at least three months ago. I hope they release v10 only when "it's ready" to be usable with their chosen maintenance process.

Comment: I just got an email from info@wolfram.com saying that Mma 10 is scheduled to release this week.  The email touts 700 new functions, "the first version based on the complete Wolfram Language", integration with Wolfram Cloud and access to the Wolfram Knowledgebase.  New built-in areas "include machine learning, computational geometry, geographic computation, and device connectivity."